# How to Use Inheritance With MVVM in the Right Way

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to change the `CurrentCarViewModel`'s model Type based on the selected value in a ListBox. Currently, in the ListBox's `SelectionChanged` event I use a switch statement to create a new model with the correct type inside `CurrentCarViewModel`. I don't think it's the best solution, because I feel switching the type every time I want to operate inside the CarViewModel is not good.

This is my `MainWindow.xaml`:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public CarViewModel CurrentCarViewModel { get; set; } = new CarViewModel();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ...
    }

    private void CarType_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch ((sender as ListBox).SelectedIndex)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}

public enum CarType { ElectricCar, GasCar }

public class CarViewModel
{
    public Car Model { get; set; }
    public CarType CarType { get; set; }
}

public class Car { }

public class ElectricCar : Car { }
public class GasCar : Car { }
```

and here's the `ListBox`:

```
<ListBox SelectionChanged="CarType_SelectionChanged" Grid.Row="0">
    <ListBoxItem Content="Electric Car"/>
    <ListBoxItem Content="Gas Car"/>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: You can bind selecteditem. Act in the setter for that property.

Comment: If your ListBox consists of CarType enumeration values, then in XAML you can bind the SelectedItem property to the Window's CurrentCarViewModel.CarType property: `SelectedItem ="{Binding CurrentCarViewModel.CarType, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"`

Comment: For correct work, you will need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged in the MainWindow and CarViewModel classes.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail? I will make you a sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This operation is not simple, so I made it as a sample.

**I made a sample of the source code you want. Please check it.**

> [GitHub](https://github.com/devncore/stackoverflow-sample/tree/main/src/answers/multiple-Inheritance-Items/MultipleInheritanceItems)

[image]

*Xaml*

```xml
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Cars}" 
         SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentCar}"/>
```

*ViewModel*

```cs
{
public class MainViewModel
{
    private Car _currentCar;

    private Car CurrentCar
    {
        get { return _currentCar; }
        set { _currentCar = value; CarChanged(value); }
    }

    public List<Car> Cars { get; set; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Cars = new List<Car>
        {
            new Electric { Name = "ModelS", Brand = "TESLA", BatteryCharge = 100 },
            new Gasoline { Name = "E-Class", Brand = "BENZ", Displacement = 2000 },
            new Gasoline { Name = "5-Series", Brand = "BMW", Displacement = 2000 }
        };
    }

    private void CarChanged(Car value)
    {
        if (value is Electric ele)
        {
            // Electric
            Debug.WriteLine(ele.GetType().ToString());
        }
        else if (value is Gasoline gas)
        {
            // Gasolin
            Debug.WriteLine(gas.GetType().ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

*ListBoxItem Resource*

```xml
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFFFFF"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="COL_A"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="COL_B"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Viewbox Grid.Column="0" Width="16" Height="16" Margin="4 4 8 4" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                            <Path x:Name="path" Width="24" Height="24"/>
                        </Viewbox>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="0 0 6 0" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Brand}" Margin="0 0 6 0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding Type}" Margin="0 0 0 0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="#cccccc"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF37528B"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Type}" Value="{x:Type model:Electric}">
                        <Setter TargetName="path" Property="Data" Value="{StaticResource GEO.BATTERY}"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="path" Property="Fill" Value="#FDFD86"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Type}" Value="{x:Type model:Gasoline}">
                        <Setter TargetName="path" Property="Data" Value="{StaticResource GEO.GASOLINE}"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="path" Property="Fill" Value="#FFACBBCD"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="Grid.IsSharedSizeScope" Value="True"/>
</Style>
```

*Path*

```xml
<Geometry x:Key="GEO.GASOLINE">M3,2H6C6.28,2 6.53,2.11 6.71,2.29L8.79,4.38L9.59,3.59C10,3.2 10.5,3 11,3H17C17.5,3 18,3.2 18.41,3.59L19.41,4.59C19.8,5 20,5.5 20,6V19A2,2 0 0,1 18,21H8A2,2 0 0,1 6,19V13L6,12V8C6,7.5 6.2,7 6.59,6.59L7.38,5.79L5.59,4H3V2M11,5V7H17V5H11M11.41,11L9.41,9H8V10.41L10,12.41V15.59L8,17.59V19H9.41L11.41,17H14.59L16.59,19H18V17.59L16,15.59V12.41L18,10.41V9H16.59L14.59,11H11.41M12,13H14V15H12V13Z</Geometry>
<Geometry x:Key="GEO.BATTERY">M16,15H8V6H16M16.67,4H15V2H9V4H7.33A1.33,1.33 0 0,0 6,5.33V20.67C6,21.4 6.6,22 7.33,22H16.67A1.33,1.33 0 0,0 18,20.67V5.33C18,4.6 17.4,4 16.67,4Z</Geometry>
```